# Spring and React websocket chat nor working because of CORS

Tags: reactjs, spring, heroku, cors

Probably this is a stupid question, but I have no idea how to deal with it.

I am trying to create a chat using Spring for backend and React for frontend and then deploy the backend to Heroku

The problem is that app cannot establish connection because of CORS with the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://inversedevs.herokuapp.com/ws/info?t=1606041704061' from origin 'http://localhost:3000/' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. GET https://inversedevs.herokuapp.com/ws/info?t=1606041723180 net::ERR_FAILED
```

My SockJS client looks like this

```
<SockJsClient
          url={SOCKET_URL}
          topics={['/topic/user']}
          onConnect={this.onConnected}
          onDisconnect={console.log("Disconnected!")}
          onMessage={msg => this.onMessageReceived(msg)}
          debug={false}
        />
```

And my Java code is this for controller:

```
@Controller
public class SocketController {

@MessageMapping("/user-all")
@SendTo("/topic/user")
public MessageBean send(@Payload MessageBean message) {
    return message;
}
```

}

For WebMvcConfigurer implementation

```
    @Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
   registry.addMapping("/**").allowCredentials(true).allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*");
}
```

And for WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implementation

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
    stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocket-chat")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

}

Logs show that the handshake was returned with status 200

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1):

As the error message already says, you cannot use the credentials mode with a wildcard origin. You have to either disable the credentials mode or set a specific origin in your origin accept header.

If you decide to keep credentials on and set the concrete origin, you may have to specify also the right port at your origin headers.